# Error while trying to update google sheet using PostgreSQL data via Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the below code to update the google sheet i have with the data from a PostgreSQL table.
The table refresh every 15 to 30 minute and i need to update this Google Sheet with the latest data.

Below is the Google sheet columns.Need to update the values from the database from the 4th row onwards.

[image]

Below is the code,

```
import psycopg2
import gspread
#Service client credential from oauth2client
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
# Print nicely
import pprint
#Create scope
scope =  ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

cnx_psql = psycopg2.connect(host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xx", database="postgres", user="postgres",
                         password="**********", port="5432")
print('DB connected')
psql_cursor = cnx_psql.cursor()

Sql_query = '''select product_id,low_stock_date,sku from test.low_stock_date;'''
psql_cursor.execute(Sql_query)
results = psql_cursor.fetchall()
cell_values = (results)
#print("Executed the query...")
#print(cell_values)

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/Users/lino/Documents/GS_secret/secret_key.json',scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/*****cBOfy***z8WFOS*****').sheet1
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
#Access all of the record inside that
result = sheet.get_all_record()

for i, val in enumerate(cell_values):  
    cell_list[i].value = val  
    sheet.update_cells(cell_list) 

psql_cursor.close()

cnx_psql.close()
```

Getting the below error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 123, in open
    self.list_spreadsheet_files()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gspread/utils.py", line 37, in finditem
    return next((item for item in seq if func(item)))
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lino/Documents/Googlesheet_update.py", line 30, in <module>
    sheet = client.open('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/*********').sheet1
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 131, in open
    raise SpreadsheetNotFound
gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound
```

**Note: Have shared the google sheet with the client email address.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to open the spreadsheet using the full URL, but you're using the `open` function that only works with titles.

From the [docs](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#opening-a-spreadsheet):

> You can open a spreadsheet by its title as it appears in Google Docs:
>
> ```
> sh = gc.open('My poor gym results')
> ```
>
> If you want to be specific, use a key (which can be extracted from the spreadsheet’s url):
>
> ```
> sht1 = gc.open_by_key('0BmgG6nO_6dprdS1MN3d3MkdPa142WFRrdnRRUWl1UFE')
> ```
>
> Or, if
>   you feel really lazy to extract that key, paste the entire
>   spreadsheet’s url
>
> ```
> sht2 = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Bm...FE&hl')
> ```

In your case the last example is the way to go, so use `client.open_by_url` instead of `client.open`